# How to get data from table where query condition related to query selected records

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

Context

I have the table "user_numbers" with the following records:

| id | user_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 2 | 3 | 666 |
| 3 | 4 | 123 |
| 4 | 5 | 666 |
| 5 | 6 | 555 |
| 6 | 7 | 123 |
| 7 | 7 | 444 |
| 8 | 8 | 444 |

I want to build query that find all user numbers and all user numbers that users have.

For example above I want to get user's number 3, 4, 5, 7 and 8 if i will select by the next condition user_id = 3.

For user 3 i got numbers:

- 123
- 666

For number 123 i got users:

- 4
- 7

For number 666 i got usres:

- 5

User 7 has numbers:

- 123
- 444

For number 444 i got users:

- 8

In result i got all user numbers linked by number:

| id | user_id | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 2 | 3 | 666 |
| 3 | 4 | 123 |
| 4 | 5 | 666 |
| 6 | 7 | 123 |
| 7 | 7 | 444 |
| 8 | 8 | 444 |

I create the next query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE founded_user_numbers AS (

    select
        un.id,
        un.user_id,
        un.number
    from p2p_market.user_numbers un
    where un.user_id = 1

    UNION

    select
        iun.id,
        iun.user_id,
        iun.number
    from p2p_market.user_numbers iun, founded_user_numbers fun
    where iun.number = fun.number and iun.id != fun.id and iun.user_id != fun.user_id
)

SELECT * FROM founded_user_numbers;
```

It works fine. Buy if i change UNION to UNION ALL or add order by i get infinity query.

Can anyone help me to write right condition to get required data.

Answer (score 1):

From your dataset and results, it looks like, given a user id, you want all users that have a least one number in common. I don't see the need for recursion here. Here is one way to do it with boolean window functions:

```
select user_id
from (
    select n.*, 
        bool_or(user_id = 3) over(partition by number) number_has_user_id_3
    from user_numbers n
) n
group by user_id
having bool_or(number_has_user_id_3)
order by user_id
```

`number_has_user_id_3` checks if user `3` has the same number as the one on the current row - which we can then use to filter users.

You could also use a correlated subquery (although that *might* be a less efficient approach):

```
select user_id
from user_numbers n
where exists (select 1 from user_numbers n1 where n1.number = n.number and n1.user_id = 3)
group by user_id
order by user_id
```

| user_id |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uk4tEpzv)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but I think you can achieve this by simply using a self-join.

```
select distinct test.t1_user_id from
  (select
     t1.id as t1_id
    ,t1.user_id as t1_user_id
    ,t1.number as t1_number
    ,t2.user_id as t2_user_id
    ,t2.number as t2_number
  from test t1

  left join test t2
    on t1.number = t2.number
    and t1.user_id <> t2.user_id

  where t2.user_id is not null) test
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5909f/1/0)

Comment: Hi @V.Kuznetsov, I have updated my fiddle with your new data. I'm still getting the same result using self-join with your updated changes. You could make this into a view and then query for the required user_id or number. Please accept my answer if this was helpful to you. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/68b95/2/0)

Comment: Yes. I checked you query. It works. But in your case query return all records related by number. I want to path to query user_id and start seach by numbers that user has.

Comment: Of course i can filter result of your query but it seems to me not optimazed enough

Answer (score 1):

with cte as
(
select  *
from user_numbers
where user_id = 3
)
select distinct un.user_id from cte c
,user_numbers  un
where un.number in (c.number)